# Spyder and IPython (Anaconda) not opening the correct environment in Ubuntu

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, spyder, fenics

I have Anaconda installed in Ubuntu (followed the instructions on the Anaconda site: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/linux/) and I am trying to import the fenics module in Spyder.  While I am able to import fenics from the terminal, I am not able to do so on Spyder (opened from the same environment) or IPython.

I have the environment named fenicsproject created with a fenics installation and activated in Anaconda:

```
conda create -n fenicsproject -c conda-forge fenics
source activate fenicsproject
```

I am able to import fenics if I type `python` in the terminal while in the fenicsproject environment.

```
Python 3.11.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 10 2023, 18:08:17) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or license for more information.

>>> import fenics
```

However, when I type

`spyder`

while also in the fenicsproject environment, to open the Spyder IDE, it seems to open a different environment where fenics is not installed.  Running the command

`import fenics`

from either the console or editor results in the

`No module named 'fenics'`

error.  The console in the Spyder IDE shows the header text

```
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jul 5 2023, 14:15:25) [GCC 11.2.0]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 8.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python
```

Notice that the GCC version is different in the Spyder console than the terminal.

**Conda info:**
conda version: 23.7.2
conda-build version: 3.26.0
python version: 3.11.4.final.0

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I did not have Spyder or IPython installed in the fenicsproject environment, so it defaulted to the installations in the base environment.  To install in the fenicsproject environment, I first made sure this environment is activated:

`conda activate fenicsproject`

and then ran:

`conda install ipython`

and

`conda install -c conda-forge spyder`

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Another, simpler option, is to change the Python interpreter Spyder uses to create new consoles, as described in [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment). That way you won't need to install Spyder in every env you create and want to use with it.